# Is it possible to add a Silverlight 3 out-of-browser application to the add/remove programs list?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, out-of-browser

Is it possible to include a `Silverlight` (3) out-of-browser application to the add-or-remove programs list?

The intention is to be able to remove the `OOB` application that way (not just by right-clicking from within the running app)?

If the `OOB` app is installed with a shortcut to the desktop and you try to delete the shortcut you are presented with the standard 'you are just deleting a shortcut if you want to delete the application go to add or remove programs' dialog. 
I want to tidy up this inconsistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a standard feature - you don't have to do anything - if you take a look under Add/Remove programs you should see that your application is there already.

Mike.

Comment: Am looking at my first sample/demo app for OOB (Enhanced Movie -Elephants Dream) but it's not in Add/Remove Progams. Unless VERY incorrectly named.  Is it configurable anywhere?

Comment: Have tried several apps now and no entry is apprearing in the add or remove list (even after restart) on XP. Any ideas?

Comment: Unable to recreate this on new dev machine. - Writing this off as an anomaly.